# Closing websocket connections using libcurl when server sends close signal

Tags: c, websocket, libcurl

I'm not an advanced user, so please cope with me.

I'm trying to implement a WebSocket client using libcurl, and I'm good until the last step of a connection - termination.

The general logic is as follows:

1. Client connects and sends an upgrade request.
2. Websocket server accepts/upgrades and starts sending gibberish.
3. Client adds up all the gibberish sizes.
4. Server sends a closing signal after 10 secs.

So far so good. I'm not processing the payloads of incoming messages, and I don't want to. I have very limited resources and I don't want to experience any performance loss in order to check each payload and search for a close signal.

I'm using libcurl's `easy` interface and receive data with `curl_easy_perform()`.  Is there any way to detect a close signal, or close the websocket connection after 10 secs?

Comment: HTTP and WebSockets have **very** different semantics. One is a request-response protocol, the other is a bi-directional message exchange protocol, allowing for push messages... Personally, I don't see how `libcurl` would be a good fit for WebSockets, unless WebSockets is just a bridge to some other problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Close signals are part of the WebSocket protocol at the framing layer (see RFC 6455 Sections [1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.4), [5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5), and [5.5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.1)).

AFAIK, libcurl doesn't natively support WebSockets, just HTTP (which a WebSocket uses for its opening handshake, so you can fake it with libcurl).  So, if libcurl doesn't process the WebSocket frames for you, you would have to process them yourself, even if you ignore their payloads.

Otherwise, just set a 10-second timer for yourself and close the underlying TCP connection directly, which you can get from libcurl using [`curl_easy_getinfo(CURLINFO_ACTIVESOCKET)`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_ACTIVESOCKET.html).

But, if the server is sending you a close signal, you SHOULD send one back, per [Section 5.5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.1), which means parsing the frames *properly*:

> If an endpoint receives a Close frame and did not previously send a Close frame, **the endpoint MUST send a Close frame in response**.  (When sending a Close frame in response, the endpoint typically echos the status code it received.)  It SHOULD do so as soon as practical.  An endpoint MAY delay sending a Close frame until its current message is sent (for instance, if the majority of a fragmented message is already sent, an endpoint MAY send the remaining fragments before sending a Close frame).  However, there is no guarantee that the endpoint that has already sent a Close frame will continue to process data.
>
> After both sending and receiving a Close message, an endpoint considers the WebSocket connection closed and MUST close the underlying TCP connection.  The server MUST close the underlying TCP connection immediately; **the client SHOULD wait for the server to close the connection but MAY close the connection at any time after sending and receiving a Close message**, e.g., if it has not received a TCP Close from the server in a reasonable time period.
>
> If a client and server both send a Close message at the same time, both endpoints will have sent and received a Close message and should consider the WebSocket connection closed and close the underlying TCP connection.

Comment: I don't know if this has to be another question but I'm trying to send a proper close signal back(after I accomplish this I will also implement ping/pongs). The way I do is like this; I created a struct like this `struct websocketheader {uint32_t fin:1;
uint32_t res1:1;
uint32_t res2:1;
uint32_t res3:1;
uint32_t opcode:4;
uint32_t mask:1;
uint32_t payload_len:7;};`
And trying to fill it from from first parameter of my writeback function like this`struct websocketheader wsh; memcpy(&wsh,ptr,sizeof(struct websocketheader));`But I get irrelevant op codes. Do you know where do I mess up?

Comment: That should indeed be posted as new question, so that you can provide more details and show the actual code you are trying to implement.

Comment: I posted a more detailed question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64283588/c-getting-websocket-header-fields-using-libcurl)