# C getting websocket header fields using libcurl

Tags: c, websocket, libcurl, bit-fields

As I mentioned in my previous question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64266211/c-closing-websocket-connections-when-server-sends-close-signal-using-libcurl)) I'm trying to get header fields of a websocket packet, opcode specifically.

As I read from RFC 6455 [Sec 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2) a websocket is as fallows:

```
 0                   1                   2                   3
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
     +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
     |F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
     |I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/64)           |
     |N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
     | |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
     +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     |     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
     + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
     |                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
     +-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
     | Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
     +-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     :                     Payload Data continued ...                :
     + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     |                     Payload Data continued ...                |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Since I'm only interested in opcode filed I created a struct as fallows;

```
struct websocketheader {
    uint32_t fin:1;
    uint32_t res1:1;
    uint32_t res2:1;
    uint32_t res3:1;
    uint32_t opcode:4;
    uint32_t mask:1;
    uint32_t payload_len:7;

};
```

If I'm not horribly wrong

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, p_para);
```

these two lines will pass the incoming packet to a callback function named write_data with p_para as the user data pointer.

My write_data function is as follows;

```
static size_t write_data(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{

    struct thread_para *p_thread = (struct thread_para*)stream;
    if (p_thread) { 
        struct websocketheader wsh; 
        memcpy(&wsh,ptr,sizeof(struct websocketheader));
        switch (wsh.opcode)
        {
        case CWS_OPCODE_CONTINUATION:
            printf("opcode: continuation\n");
            break;
        case CWS_OPCODE_TEXT:
            printf("opcode text\n");
            break;
        case CWS_OPCODE_BINARY:
            printf("opcode binary\n");
        case CWS_OPCODE_CLOSE:
            printf("opcode close\n");
            break;
        case CWS_OPCODE_PING: 
            printf("opcode ping\n");
            break;
        case CWS_OPCODE_PONG:
            printf("opcode pong\n");        
        default:
            printf("Unknown opcode\n");
            break;
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock(&p_thread->lock);
        p_thread->now += size * nmemb;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&p_thread->lock);
                 
    }
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

I was expecting to get first 16 bits written to my struct correctly but the prints showed me that is not the case. I'm currently printing random opcodes which indicates I have failed to read the opcodes correctly.

As I mentioned in my previous question I have zero interest in payloads since they are garbage and since I can get total length from libcurl via `size * nmemb`, I also have no interest the payload length field of websocket header. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and I have limited knowledge on how to work with bits.

I would really appreciate if you can point me out what I'm doing wrong and I'm also open other suggestions which would do the job in a different way.

Comment: The data received in the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback is arbitrary, there is no guarantee that you will receive exactly `sizeof(websocketheader)` number of bytes each time it is called. Not to mention you are not even accounting for packet payloads. It is your responsibility to buffer the incoming data and parse the buffer as needed. Wait until a full `websocketheader` is in the buffer then parse and remove it, then buffer and discard however many `payload_len` bytes the header says, then buffer and parse the next header, buffer and skip its payload, and so on.

Comment: Also, there is no guarantee that the compiler will order bitfields the way you are expecting, so consider using manual bitmasks/bitshifts instead to ensure you are looking at the correct bits.

Comment: Network byte ordering might not match your system's byte ordering, which would result in your code failing to align the bit fields in the struct with the network data (which could fail for other reasons too). You need to manually parse the bit fields or use [an existing WebSocket parser](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/01308406483a079b40288e98c00e3b90b4d36ad3/lib/facil/http/parsers/websocket_parser.h#L378-L417).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do it this simply.

You've assumed that you always get at least `sizeof(struct websocketheader)` bytes in that callback, but that is not the case. You get `size * nmemb` bytes. TCP/IP is a stream protocol.

You need to add received bytes into a buffer, then parse websocket frames *only* when you have enough bytes to do so.